# Google Maps API access release

Tags: android, maps

I'm having issues with google maps, I have got it working with the debug key but when try the release version, I'm getting a blank screen instead of the map. I've followed instructions and signed the release key.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin>keytool 
 -list -v -keystore C:\DecSurfApp\key.jks
```

Gives me this key:

```
SHA1: B6:1F:24:AB:##:8A:C9:EF:C9:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##
```

Which I've used to generate api key

```
B6:1F:24:AB:##:8A:C9:EF:C9:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##;
com.nitinarya.surfalarmclockrelease
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Added AndridManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.nitinarya.surfalarmclockrelease.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

google_maps_api.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="google_maps_key_instructions" templateMergeStrategy="replace"><!--




Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
string in this file.
--></string>

<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">####################3PvXCg</string>
```

Comment: post your manifest file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with wrong `Google API` key. So you need to use `SHA` fingerprint while you are going to release your app.

For example , after final deployment of your application you can able to find `SHA` finger print while you'r going to finish (generate apk) so use that `SHA` finger print and generate google map key and add it to your manifest file and run once. After that just release your apk and deploy it. It will show you google map.

***NOTE:*** Also check that you have added all necessary information to your `Androidmanifest.xml` file.

Comment: I have used the SHA1 fingerprint to generate the google map key

Comment: Its for debug mode. You need to use SHA while for release mode.

Comment: It worked!!! :D 

I was putting the release key in google_maps_api.xml(debug).

Thank you RockStar :) I was stuck on this for days and had given up.

Comment: Yeah. thats the problem. Glad to help you!!